# CosmosDB MongoDB adapter projection not working

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm making request to CosmosDB database via MongoDB adapter from HapiJS server.
My request looks like so:

```
        dbo
          .collection("storage")
          .find(query, function(
            findErr,
            result
          ) {
            if (findErr) throw findErr;
            (async function() {
              output = result.toArray()
            })();
          });
```

And it works allright. But if I'm trying to add projection (from official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-query-mongodb)) nothing changing at all.
I'm adding projection like this:

```
  .find(query, {data:false}, function( ...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my question is duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451300/projection-not-working-with-db-collection-find-in-mongo),
It is worked like so:

```
 .find(query, {projection:{data:false}}...
```

Comment: You could mark yourself to end this case,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the mongodb query syntax listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_query.asp), only query filter need to be defined. So you could adjust your code like:

```
var query = { "data": false };
dbo.collection("storage").find(query, function(
            findErr.....
```

Comment: But I've got another data in query, by which the find is executed:
`
query={ type: "Sometype", id:123}
`

Comment: @Justice47 How's your `query` like?

Comment: its actuallty called mongodb projection - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Comment: And this is example from CosmosDB docs - 
`db.families.find( { id: "WakefieldFamily" }, { children: true } )`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-query-mongodb