# Mongodb returns all fields even with projection specified

Tags: regex, mongodb, projection

Update:

I want to only return all documents that fit four characters of a given username that is entered. So if I have a list of usernames and I type in mango3333, all usernames that are starting with "mang" should be returned. I used a regexp for that, and now I want to only return for example the username and the id of that document and not all fields, but it returns all fields.

An example document looks like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5d75299b0d01830"}, 
"User": 
{ "username":"mango",
  "userid":"8b8d25d3-3fe6-4d1c",
  "token":"token",
  "pw":"password",
  "statusmessage":"",
  "lastlogin":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1567959451354"}},
  "registered":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1567959451354"}
}
```

This is my query:

```
const db = dbClient.db(dbName);
const regexp = new RegExp(username, "gi");
db.collection(collectionName).find({ "User.Username": regexp }, { "User.Username": 1, "User.UserID": 1, "User.Statusmessage": 1 })
.toArray()
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
.catch(err => console.error(`Failed to get results: ${err}`));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is about how to define a regex in a mongdb query, that part works fine for me, my issue is about returning only specific fields from a document instead of all fields

Comment: And just how do you suppose OP can supply a reproducible example? @JohnnyHK Is the code snippet not good enough? Anywho, [you can try something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610702/10431732) as it worked for that person (who was having the same issue as you)...

Comment: @MattOestreich this solution works, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2nd portion of the `find` method is an options object, not just projection. The projection portion of the query will need to be specified in this `options` object. Try the following:

```
db.collection(collectionName).find(
  { "User.Username": regexp }, 
  { 
     projection: { 
       "User.Username": 1, 
       "User.UserID": 1, 
       "User.Statusmessage": 1 
     }
  }
)
.toArray()
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

See https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Collection.html#find