# mongodb nodejs pipeline for find items in array return all about collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hello to everyone...

#### premise

I have [mongodb 7.X](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/release-notes/7.0/) + [mongo driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/v3.6/quick-start/) installed in linux + nodejs (i don't have clear why in npm the version is 6.3.0), and I trying to extrapolate only one single data from an array in a collection.

_note 1: no mongoose.
*note 2: for this example, "single data" is truly one, but out of test i need of the complete object with that data. Anyway...*

the solution is liken this [online exemple](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wr-BSL2ysRl) `https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wr-BSL2ysRl` and now I have a problem: that not working in real for me. Not working EVERY solution... I don't know why:

#### exposed process

my data collection for testing:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "65bb73c6338793c4c38e919e",
    "season-2024": [
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e919f",
        "fakedata": 30289
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a0",
        "fakedata": 268
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a1",
        "fakedata": 186353
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a2",
        "fakedata": 7346228
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a3",
        "fakedata": 23688922
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a4",
        "fakedata": 98903
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a5",
        "fakedata": 5270371
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a6",
        "fakedata": 260862
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a7",
        "fakedata": 186543
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a8",
        "fakedata": 1314
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a9",
        "fakedata": 1468
      },
      {
        "_id": "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91aa",
        "fakedata": 186734
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Currentry i do:

1 get the collection
2 use find model for extract from the array

```js
let collection = await params.database.collection( params.collection ) // return the collection


let finder = await collection.find({},{
    "season-2024": {
      $elemMatch: {
        _id: "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a0"
      }
    }
}).toArray()

console.log("finder result",finder)
```

> yes, I tried with `_id: new ObjectId("65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a0")`

the "finder result" is (obviously wrong):

```js
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('65bb73c6338793c4c38e919e'),
    'season-2024': [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  }
```

Someone can explain what do i wrong??
why in tester mongodb v6 run but in real localhost not? is the mongodb v7?

---

### solution:

after more research i find this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610702/23331408) by [jo-gro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9313209/jo-gro):
`https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610702/23331408`

i don't know why but it need to separate in two functions the data entries:

```
let finder = await collection
                .find({}) // you can do more...
                .project({
                    "season-2024": {
                         $elemMatch: {
                            _id: "65bb73d5338793c4c38e91a0"
                         }
                     }
                }).toArray()
```

Where is in the reference in the guidelines ? "mystery..."

Comment: Would it be possible that you put the `$elemMatch` clause in [query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) instead of [projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) like you did in playground?

Comment: you are sharp my friend, and I tested it but.. not.  it changes in the tester but not locally.  In filter it returns each element, in project it returns only the element concerned. However, locally it always gives the same result.